# Word document from S3 proxy using AWS API in Angularjs, fails to open "select encoding that makes your document readable"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get, aws-api-gateway, binaryfiles

I am trying to load/save a document from S3 using AWS API (S3 proxy) and angular js. code as below

1. response type is marked as array buffer and is then converted as blob with UTF8 and type as "application/msword" (verified content type from S3 API)
2. download is successful however the file isn't showing up and an error  "select encoding that makes your document readable"
3. tried with pdf document with type application/pdf, pdf opens but shows no data. 
   Any clue whats wrong here

---

```
   $scope.URL =  "https://jkq1yea3e5.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Prod" + "/s3resources/"+"testfolder/"+ $scope.filename;
          $http.get($scope.URL, {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.info = "Read '" + $scope.URL + "' with " + data.byteLength
        + " bytes in a variable of type '" + typeof(data) + "'";
       blob= new Blob([data], {type: $scope.type+";charset=utf-8"});
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
        linkElement.setAttribute("download", $scope.filename);
        linkElement.click();

        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, $scope.filename,true);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for hours, here is what worked for me.

added application/msword in binary types for the AWS API

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-workflow.html